# ctypes binding call throws segmentation fault

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I'm trying to create simple bindings to the [MD4C](https://github.com/mity/md4c) project but get a weird segmentation fault thrown when I attempt to call `md_parse`. I'm not too well versed in C so the code bellow describes my best attempt to tackle this issue. I acquired `libmd4c.dylib` by cloning and building the project with `cmake` according to their instructions:

```
brew install cmake
git clone https://github.com/mity/md4c.git
cd md4c
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

My best guess about what's wrong is the actual arguments I'm passing to the final call. Here is the full code:

```
import ctypes
import sys

lib = ctypes.CDLL('libmd4c.dylib')

def generic_cb(*args, **kwargs):

    print(args, kwargs)

def block_cb(code, detail, udata):

    generic_cb(code, details, udata)

    return 0

c_func_block_cb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p
)

c_func_block_cb_p = ctypes.POINTER(
    c_func_block_cb
)


c_func_text_cb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_wchar_p,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.c_void_p
)

c_func_text_cb_p = ctypes.POINTER(
    c_func_text_cb
)


c_func_debug_log_cb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_char_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
)

c_func_debug_log_cb_p = ctypes.POINTER(
    c_func_debug_log_cb
)


c_func_syntax_cb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
)

c_func_syntax_cb_p = ctypes.POINTER(
    c_func_syntax_cb
)


class Structure(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        (
            'abi_version',
            ctypes.c_uint
        ),
        (
            'flags',
            ctypes.c_uint
        ),

        (
            'enter_block',
            c_func_block_cb_p
        ),
        (
            'leave_block',
            c_func_block_cb_p
        ),
        (
            'enter_span',
            c_func_block_cb_p
        ),
        (
            'leave_span',
            c_func_block_cb_p
        ),

        (
            'text',
            c_func_text_cb_p
        ),
        (
            'debug_log',
            c_func_debug_log_cb_p
        ),
        (
            'syntax',
            c_func_syntax_cb_p
        )
    ]

StructurePointer = ctypes.POINTER(Structure)


c_block_cb = c_func_block_cb(block_cb)

c_block_cb_p = c_func_block_cb_p(c_block_cb)


c_text_cb = c_func_text_cb(generic_cb)

c_text_cb_p = c_func_text_cb_p(c_text_cb)


c_debug_log_cb = c_func_debug_log_cb(generic_cb)

c_debug_log_cb_p = c_func_debug_log_cb_p(c_debug_log_cb)


c_syntax_cb = c_func_syntax_cb(generic_cb)

c_syntax_cb_p = c_func_syntax_cb_p(c_syntax_cb)


struct = Structure(
    0,
    0,
    c_block_cb_p,
    c_block_cb_p,
    c_block_cb_p,
    c_block_cb_p,
    c_text_cb_p,
    c_debug_log_cb_p,
    None
)

value = '**hello**'

value_p = ctypes.c_wchar_p(value)

struct_p = StructurePointer(struct)

size = ctypes.c_uint(len(value))

func = lib.md_parse

func.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_wchar_p,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    StructurePointer,
    ctypes.c_void_p
]

func.restype = ctypes.c_int

func.errcheck = print

udata = ctypes.c_int()

udata_p = ctypes.byref(udata)

result = lib.md_parse(value_p, size, struct_p, udata_p)

print(result)
```

Please let me know if you have any insights to share.

Comment: `udata_p` is a reference to a `c_int`, but `func.argtypes` earlier indicates it should be a `StructurePointer`.  Without an [mcve] that's all I see.

Comment: The code I provide is my full script @MarkTolonen, I added a few details about how I acquired the library right above and also updated the code with my newest attempt to get this to work, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to build this so others may be able to answer your question?

Comment: Added building instructions :) @S.S.Anne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes to the python code in this question prevent various segfaults and exceptions.

```
--- md_parse.py     2020-01-22 22:47:31.802934477 -0500
+++ md_parse.py     2020-01-22 23:56:50.874006725 -0500
@@ -7,7 +7,9 @@

     print(args, kwargs)

-def block_cb(code, detail, udata):
+    return 0
+
+def block_cb(code, details, udata):

     generic_cb(code, details, udata)

@@ -27,7 +29,7 @@

 c_func_text_cb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
     ctypes.c_int,
-    ctypes.c_wchar_p,
+    ctypes.c_wchar,
     ctypes.c_uint,
     ctypes.c_void_p
 )
@@ -72,28 +74,28 @@

         (
             'enter_block',
-            c_func_block_cb_p
+            c_func_block_cb
         ),
         (
             'leave_block',
-            c_func_block_cb_p
+            c_func_block_cb
         ),
         (
             'enter_span',
-            c_func_block_cb_p
+            c_func_block_cb
         ),
         (
             'leave_span',
-            c_func_block_cb_p
+            c_func_block_cb
         ),

         (
             'text',
-            c_func_text_cb_p
+            c_func_text_cb
         ),
         (
             'debug_log',
-            c_func_debug_log_cb_p
+            c_func_debug_log_cb
         ),
         (
             'syntax',
@@ -127,12 +129,12 @@
struct = Structure(
     0,
     0,
-    c_block_cb_p,
-    c_block_cb_p,
-    c_block_cb_p,
-    c_block_cb_p,
-    c_text_cb_p,
-    c_debug_log_cb_p,
+    c_block_cb,
+    c_block_cb,
+    c_block_cb,
+    c_block_cb,
+    c_text_cb,
+    c_debug_log_cb,
     None
 )
```

The first patch chunk fixes a discrepancy in the `block_cb` argument list, and fixes `generic_cb` to return the expected type (omitting the changes in the first chunk will reveal some exceptions hidden behind the segfaults).

The other changes in the patch prevent a couple of different segfaults, and amount to not using pointer types in various places. There is some dead code left behind by those changes, but removing that dead code would make the patch bigger, with no relevance to the segfaults which are the focus of this question.

I performed my testing on a Debian system, but I wouldn't expect the results to vary materially on other platforms.